# Nginx: Escaping # in url rewrite

Tags: facebook-graph-api, nginx

I have a MVC JavaScript application that needs to support Facebook sharing, which means it needs to support unique OG meta HTML tags.

I'm doing an Nginx rewrite that will detect the Facebook crawler to server a custom version of the app with the proper OG tag for that section but Apache is ignore everything after the # sign (as server-side should do since that's a browser feature.) I would like to escape the "#" in my rewrite but am not sure how to do it in Nginx:

```
location / {
  if ($http_user_agent ~* 'facebookexternalhit') {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /og.php?url=http://$host$uri;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    break;
  }
  root /var/www/html/site.net;
}
```

Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot or don't have to. If you have an URL in your browser like `http://www.example.tld/site.html#anchor` then your browser's request will only consist of the non-anchor part: `http://www.example.tld/site.html`. After receiving the content the browser will look for a named anchor called `anchor` and scroll the page so that its content is visible.

Meaning nginx will never see the character `#`.

If, on the other hand, a website contains a link with `#` being part of the path part of the URL (and this is rather rare) then it has to be escaped with the usual URL escaping of `%xx` with `xx` being the hexadecimal number of that chacter -- `%23` in the case of `#`.

Comment: Moritz: I am successfully proxy_pass-ing to Apache, as written above: `rewrite ^(.*)$ /og.php?url=http://$host$uri;`, which works fine (including hash character). I understand neither Nginx or Apache see the hash but it is being rewritten properly, I just need the following: `rewrite ^(.*)$ /og.php?url=escape(http://$host$uri);`

Comment: You're right, of course, that escaping the URL if turned into a GET parameter is necessary. Didn't think of it. You question was about the # though, and for that my answer still applies.

Comment: Yes, but my problem is the escaping word above doesn't exist in Nginx as far as I know.

Comment: Guys I need this rewrite rule to work  

`rewrite ^/ref/(.*)$ /%23/home/$1 last;`  

I type:  http://example.com/ref/xyz  

I get:  

Cannot GET /%2523/home/xyz