# how to create website redirect with a # in the link

Tags: redirect, nginx

I need to create a redirect in the Serverblock on my nginx Server.
I want to use the same code which is already working for other redirects:

http://www.domain.com/text

```
    location /text {
    rewrite ^/.* http://www.domain.com/target permanent;
    }
```

this works fine!

But this code is not working with a specific link

http://www.domain.com/#text/text

```
    location /#text/text {
    rewrite ^/.* http://www.domain.com/target permanent;
    }
```

I believe it is because of the # sign but my problem is I need the exact URL name with the # sign. Is there a way to uncomment a # sign or do I need to go a complete different way?

Comment: Try escaping the # with `%23` as-described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9794542/3394342

Comment: Thank you, I tried but it didnt work

       location /%23text/text {
        rewrite ^/.* http://www.domain.com/target permanent;
        }