# NGINX proxy url with hash '#' character

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I would like to publicly route a URL **abc.domain.com** to the internal URL **http://host.local:2324/#12345**. "#12345" is fixed and can not be changed.

**server_name    abc.domain.com

proxy_pass       http://host.local:2324/#12345

sub_filer        host.local:2324/#12345 abc.domain.com**

In Nginx, however, comments are implied by #. Thus, the rule proxy_pass and sub_filter is cut off.
A masking with **"%23"** can not be implemented unfortunately.

Does anyone have an idea here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nginx: Escaping # in url rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779163/nginx-escaping-in-url-rewrite)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain why `%23` can't be used.

Comment: Have you tried using double quotes around the values containing a `#` character?

Comment: The UI Service Application does not understand **%23**. Since I have no way to change anything, it has to go without it.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the "UI Service Application" but `%23` is the way of escaping the '#' character in nginx.

Comment: If I use %23, I need %23 processing on the URL evaluation logic.
Unfortunately, there is no transparent masking of '#' in nginx.
Will use a different proxy.

Answer (score 0):

In url you can't use explicit #. 
When you enter in browser http://localhost:2324/#12345., browser will be open page before # and then find css id #12345 and move to them. 
If you want to use # in url you must decode url, as http://localhost:2324/%2312345

This is working url redirect nginx code:

```
rewrite ^/([^\#]+)\#([^\#]+)$ /proxy_url/$1#$2 redirect;
```

[Nginx: Escaping # in url rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779163/nginx-escaping-in-url-rewrite)